# How to add a border to an element with a linear gradient and opacity?

Tags: html, css, svg

I need to add a border to my element as a linear-gradient color, with the colors mixed with the current background color:

```css
html, body {
    background-color: #131519;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;

  // I need to apply the border as in SVG
  // This is my current work, but it does not work
  // The color is white and border-radius is not respected
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)) 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Here is an SVG that implements what I want, but I need to use CSS.

```xml
<svg width="1328" height="293" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect x="1" y="1" width="100%" height="100%" rx="10" stroke="url(#paint1_linear_61_8)" stroke-width="2" style="mix-blend-mode:overlay"/>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="paint1_linear_61_8" x1="664" y1="0" x2="664" y2="293" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop stop-color="white"/>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

The final result I expect:

[image]

Comment: You need to explain the issue in more details. Would you like to use the SVG as a border to an HTML element? You show the code for the SVG, but could you also add the HTML (like an example where you use the background that you write about).

Comment: Thanks. I edited it, do you have any other questions?

Answer (score -1):

add a parent div with the gradient-background, give it a padding the same width as the border width - that's it

```css
.parent {
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
padding: 5px;
background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
border-radius: 5px;
}

.box {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
<div class='box '></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, but that's not what I said.